# Multiple checkbox values and a "check-all checkbox" value saved with localstorage

Tags: jquery, checkbox, local-storage

I have set up localstorage to save the value of my checkboxes and have a "check all" and "uncheck all" function. I am trying to implement a way to show only the checked items when a specific checkbox, separate from the "check all" group of checkboxes, is checked. The problem I am having is saving that checkbox value into localstorage. 
I see in the console that my `formValues` checkboxes as well as my separate `showHide` checkbox are saved in localstorage. I am just getting stumped at the show and hide functionality working with the check all functionality.

**Addendum:** The issues are

1. the state of the `$show` checkbox seems to be correctly saved in localstorage (in the console) but the fadeout and FadeIn function doesn't show on reloading the page.
2. If I uncheck a checkbox and then check "Show Checked", the unchecked div is hidden as it should be, but when I then click the "Check All" button (which sets "Show Checked" to false) that hidden (unchecked) div does not change to checked and then show.

It seems my issue is not so much with saving the checkbox state, since that seems to work in localstorage,  but with adding and removing the class "hidden-print" when the checkbox is checked and page reloads. The console shows that the class is not added to the save checked checkbox.

I realize this may be confusing and I may be trying to do to much with check all and hiding divs. Any help or direction is appreciated!

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/macsupport/pen/mGgPYe?editors=0010)

```js
var formValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("formValues")) || {};
var showHide = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("showHide")) || {};
var $checkboxes = $("#checkbox-container input.drug");
var $button = $("#checkbox-container .checkall");
var $show = $("#checkbox-container #hideDrugs");

if ($show.prop('checked', true)) {
  $('.Rtable-row.hidden-print').fadeOut(200);
} else {
  $('.Rtable-row.hidden-print').fadeIn(200);
}
$show.on("change", function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.Rtable-row.hidden-print').fadeOut(200);
  } else {
    $('.Rtable-row.hidden-print').fadeIn(200);
  }
});

function allChecked() {
  return $checkboxes.length === $checkboxes.filter(":checked").length;
}

function updateButtonStatus() {
  $button.text(allChecked() ? "Uncheck all" : "Check all");
  $button.filter(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == 'Check all') {
      $show.prop('checked', false);
    } else {}
  })
}

function handleButtonClick() {
  $checkboxes.prop("checked", allChecked() ? false : true);
}

function updateStorage() {
  $checkboxes.each(function() {
    formValues[this.id] = this.checked;
    if (this.checked) {
      $(this).parents('.Rtable-row').removeClass('hidden-print');
    } else {
      $(this).parents('.Rtable-row').addClass('hidden-print');
    }
  });
  $show.each(function() {
    showHide = this.checked;
    if (this.checked) {
      console.log('checked')
    } else {
      console.log('unchecked')
    }
  });

  formValues["buttonText"] = $button.text();
  localStorage.setItem("formValues", JSON.stringify(formValues));
  localStorage.setItem("showHide", JSON.stringify(showHide));
}

$button.on("click", function() {
  handleButtonClick();
  updateButtonStatus();
  updateStorage();
});

$show.on("change", function() {
  updateStorage();
});
$checkboxes.on("change", function() {
  updateButtonStatus();
  updateStorage();
});

// On page load
$.each(formValues, function(key, value) {
  $("#" + key).prop("checked", value);
});
$show.prop('checked', showHide.value);
$button.text(formValues["buttonText"]);
```

Comment: Can you make it clearer what exactly is wrong/doesn't produce the expected results with your current code?

Comment: Added more info, but could be more confusing! lol

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jvRmMr?editors=0010 Here's a fix for your first issue (check differences with your own codepen), too tired to look into the other one for now, I'll get at it tomorrow and post an answer if no one has helped you by then.

Comment: Thanks for the effort!

Comment: @Jeto I added some additional info to my question. The main problem is that the class is not being added when the page reloads, even though the checkbox state is saved.